# Accessing a parameter passed to one function in another function

Tags: python

I have two functions:

```
def f1(p1=raw_input("enter data")):
    ...do something

def f2(p2=raw_input("enter data")):
    ...do something else
```

p1 and p2 are the same data, so I want to avoid asking for the input twice. Is there a way I can pass the argument supplied to f1 to f2 without asking for it again? Ideally I would be able to use something like you would in a class. Like `f1.p1`Is this possible?

EDIT: To add some clarity, I looked into using the ** operator to unpack arguments and I'm aware that using the main body of the program to access the arguments is cleaner. However, the former does not match what I'm trying to do, which is gain a better understanding of what is accessible in a function. I also looked at using the `inspect` and `locals`, but these are for inspecting arguments within the function, not outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, depending on your needs.  The best would be to ask in the main program, and simply pass that value to each function as you call it.  Another possibility is to have one function call the other.

```
# Main program
user_input = raw_input("enter data")
f1(user_input)
f2(user_input)
```

> Ideally I would be able to use something like you would in a class.
>   Like f1.p1  Is this possible?

That's an advanced technique, and generally dangerous practice.  Yes, you can go into the call stack, get the function object, and grab the local variable -- but the function has to be active for this to have any semantic use.

That's not the case you presented.  In your code, you have **f1** and **f2** independently called.  Once you return from **f1**, the value of **p1** is popped off the stack and lost.

*If* you have **f1** call **f2**, then it's possible for **f2** to reach back to its parent and access information.  *Don't go there.*  :-)

Comment: You're right. I've amended the program to do that. I will upvote your answer. Just wondering if there's another way, just for completeness' sake. I looked at using the ** operator, but I don't think that is suitable for my needs.

Comment: Right; not suitable.  That's for passing pointer arguments, often from interfaces outside Python.  Also, remember to "accept" and answer, so SO can archive the question.

Comment: Will do. I hope someone else will contribute and let me know if accessing the argument like you would in a class e.g: `f1.p1 ` and pass it to f2 works. Hope this is ok.

Comment: _If you have f1 call f2, then it's possible for f2 to reach back to its parent and access information. Don't go there. :-)_ It would be interesting to know how this is done even if I never use it! Any clues on what to Google for please?

Comment: This is beyond SO's charter, but once ... I'd try "access stack function attributes".  A local variable is a function attribute.  Please don't try this without proper ventilation, and keep it away from small children.

Comment: I promise I'll be careful :)