# (Python) How to store a function's argument to use it later into another function

Tags: python, function, arguments

say I have a function that takes two argument, a list and a number:

```
def function1(list1,n):
      #do something
```

Say that I also have another function defined later on:

```
def function2(list2,x):
    #do something
```

I need to use the argument `list1` inside the `function2`. How can I do that? I tried to save list1 as a variable using `copy.deepcopy()`, but it still gives me error. How can I do that?

Comment: Pass `list1` as an argument to `function2`. Also, whenever you get an error, please say what it is. Just the fact that you got one isn't insanely helpful.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654905/accessing-a-parameter-passed-to-one-function-in-another-function/42654947#42654947)

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for not giving you guys the error. Without deepcopying the variable, it just says "list1 not defined", which makes sense. After deep.copying it tho I get "local variable list1 referenced before assignment"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're modifying the list in f1, return `list1` from `f1`:

```
def f1(list1, n): 
    # do something to the list and n 
    return list1 

def f2(list2, n)
    # do something 

x = f1(list1, n) 

f2(x, n)
```